# Remote Desktop suddenly unable to connect to a computer on the network

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, home-networking

Yesterday I had perfect Remote Desktop access to all the computers on my network.  This morning, for apparently no reason, I am unable to connect to one of the computers on the network.  The target computer is running Windows 10 and installed an update overnight.  If I can find no solution to this then I will have to try restoring from yesterday's system image, but hoping to find another solution.

I am able to view files in the target computer by going through `network` on any of the other computers on the network; it is just the Remote Desktop that will not connect.

I am able to Remote Desktop connect to other desktops from the target computer, but not to the target computer from any of the other computers on the network.

I get the same problem whether trying to access the target computer either from inside or outside the network.  All other computers on the network have no problems.

I have tried running the windows troubleshooter for remote connections but it finds no problems.

I have checked all the port numbers and firewall permissions; the target computer is on port 3388 so I have made firewall exceptions for this port - regardless, it was working fine yesterday with the same configuration so I am at a loss.

Comment: What was the update?

Comment: @Dave it was KB3163018.  I have tried uninstalling the update but no change.

Comment: with "the target computer is on port 3388" you mean you have checked with `netstat -an | findstr 3388` on the target that it is listening and with `telnet targetIP 3388` from another PC that the port is available?

Comment: I just reinitialized Windows 10 and the problem has gone away now.  Not sure what the cause was but this seems to have been the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I reinitialised Windows 10 by going to `Settings > Update and Security > Recovery > Reset this PC`.  I had already tried uninstalling the recent updates and going back to a restore point before the problem started but this made no difference. The problem seems to have gone away for the moment at least.

Although this does not give an explanation for the problem, it seems like a straight forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

The update might disabled the remote desktop feature on the specific target?
on your win10 target please search for system and clieck return button.
go to "Remote Settings" on the left hand side of the window. then on the "Remote Desktop section make sure the "Allow remote connections to this computer" is checked. also, make sure your user have permissions using the "select user" button.

Comment: I have made sure that remote connections are allowed - no change.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  This should have been submitted as a comment.

Comment: This actually worked for me.  However, my problem started after the Fall Creator's update installed on a PC on my home network.  However, I had to do one thing:  I first had to check "DON'T allow remote connections to this computer."  And then click apply.  After that, I re-selected "Allow remote connections to this computer" and then I was able to remote to it!  Thanks for the suggestion which put me on the right path!